# Moving the saddle point of a logistic function

Tags: functions

I have a function $s(a, b) \rightarrow [0,1]$ describing the similarity of $a$ and $b$ according to some heuristic (if $s(a, b) = 1$, $a$ and $b$ are similar according to the heuristic).

I want to map $s(a, b)$ via a function $\text{conf}(s(a, b)) \rightarrow [0,1]$ describing the confidence that $a$ and $b$ are similar.

$\text{conf}(s(a, b))$ should be $> 0.5$ if $s(a, b) > d$, where $0 < d < 1$ is some threshold, and I want $\text{conf}(s(a, b)) <= 0.5$ if $s(a, b) <= d$. Additionally, I want to dampen the effect of slight changes of $s(a, b)$ around 0 and 1.

For $d = 0.5$, I am at the moment using this logistic function:

$$\text{conf}\left(s\left(a, b\right)\right) = 0.5 + 0.5 \times \text{tanh}\left(\frac{s(a, b) - d}{\frac{1}{2}d}\right).$$

For $d = 0.5$, it works perfectly. However, if I move the threshold $d$ (for example, to $d = 0.2$), the saddle point of $\text{conf}$ is at $0.2$ as desired, but the function now already reaches values $> 0.99$ for $s(a, b) > 0.4297$.

How can I get a logistic function where I can move the saddle point freely, but at the same time retain a behavior on both sides of the saddle point that is similar to the case of $d = 0.5$ (I apologize for the unmathematical wording)?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to control how "broad" your logistic function is by modifying:

$$c(s;d)=\frac{1}{2}\Big(1+\tanh\Big(\frac{s-d}{f(d)}\Big)\Big)$$

Now you can impose an extra constraint on the confidence function, which controls how broad it is for different values of the threshold . In your case, one could for example fix a specific value of the function, $c(a;d)=0.75$, where $a$ could be a fixed value which can be specified per your purposes-if the current function being used is satisfactory one could determine it as the number that satisfies $ \frac{1}{2}\Big(1+\tanh\Big(\frac{a-0.5}{0.25}\Big)\Big)=0.75$.

Then this determines the function $f(d)$ :

$$f(d)=\frac{a-d}{\text{arctanh}(1/2)}$$

This function passes through the point $(a,0.75)$ no matter what the threshold is, thus alleviating the problem of the breadth becoming smaller as the threshold becomes smaller. This is by no means a unique choice for $f(d)$, and one can manipulate it's form to obtain different breadths at different choices of threshold according to taste.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! But is there any way to make sure that the confidence function hits the same values at $0$ and $1$?

Comment: This is not possible with such a simple choice of function, if you would like to map 0 and 1 to a standard value maybe you would be better off using an extrapolating polynomial with the added requirement that a saddle should happen at $d$.

Comment: The polynomial should be a quartic so one can enforce all of the following: $c(0)=0, c(1)=1, c(d)=1/2, c''(d)=0, c'(x)>0~\forall x$